# Why isn't Facebook recognizing my OG tags?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Working on a site that contains OpenGraph tags. However, when trying to share one of those pages, the Facebook preview isn't populating properly:

For example: https://www.hkinsurance.com/2018/03/noise-reduction-restaurant/

OG Tags:

```
 <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US"/>
 <meta property="og:site_name" content="H&amp;K Insurance"/>
 <meta property="og:title" content="Noise Reduction for Your Restaurant - H&amp;K Insurance"/>
 <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.hkinsurance.com/2018/03/noise-reduction-restaurant/"/>
 <meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
 <meta property="og:description" content="Reducing noise is key to maintaining ambiance in your restaurant. Learn about noise reduction techniques on our blog. Call 617-612-6515 to evaluate your insurance coverages."/>
```

Comment: You can use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ to test your page

Comment: This is what your server returns to Facebook https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.hkinsurance.com%2F2018%2F03%2Fnoise-reduction-restaurant%2F

Comment: The debug tool says it can't read my OpenGraph tags, but they're clearly there...what am I missing?

Comment: https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=www.hkinsurance.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enter your page url and click **Scrape Again** button in the next page.
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

If this doesn't help maybe you don't have property requirements for og tags.

- Check out this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices
- For og:image if you changed image for same url, sometimes facebook caching the image and Scrape button doesn't work. You have two options: wait until facebook cleans its cache or change image name and og:image propery path for the new image and **Scrape Again**.

Comment: I've gone through the "scrape again" process a few times, on any page on that site, and nothing seems to be working.

Comment: You should fix this error first. Is your SSL is real or fake? SSL Error
Can't validate SSL Certificate. Either it is self-signed (which will cause browser warnings) or it is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of confusion, I discovered that my file was in UTF-16 format, not UTF-8.  As soon as I converted it, everything worked.

Comment: which type of file?

Comment: n1koloza, see my own resolution above.  My file was encoded incorrectly.  Once I fixed it, everything was fine.

Comment: about which file i cannot understad :X